# if line not startswith item from a list

Tags: python

I would like to know how to take those items from a list that don't start like some of the items from another list.

I want to make something like:

```
list_results = ['CONisotig124', '214124', '2151235', '235235', 'PLEisotig1235', 'PLEisotig2354', '12512515', 'CONisotig1325', '21352']

identifier_list=['CON','VEN','PLE']


for item in list_results:
  if not item.startswith(     "some ID from the identifier_list"     ):
      print item
```

So, how do I say:

```
if not item.startswith(     "some ID from the identifier_list"     ):
```

Comment: another for loop inside the list_results loops could do the trick

Answer (score 7):

[`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) can take a *tuple* of strings to test for:

> *prefix* can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.

Use this together with a list comprehension:

```
identifier_list = ('CON', 'VEN', 'PLE')  # tuple, not list

[elem for elem in list_results if not elem.startswith(identifier_list)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_results = ['CONisotig124', '214124', '2151235', '235235', 'PLEisotig1235', 'PLEisotig2354', '12512515', 'CONisotig1325', '21352']
>>> identifier_list = ('CON', 'VEN', 'PLE')  # tuple, not list
>>> [elem for elem in list_results if not elem.startswith(identifier_list)]
['214124', '2151235', '235235', '12512515', '21352']
```

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty straight-forward, you almost got it:

```
for item in list_results:
  bad_prefix = False
  for id in identifier_list:
    if item.startswith(id):
      bad_prefix = True
      break

  if not bad_prefix:
    print item
```